# Cast Function to display only the month and day from a datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

```
SELECT 
    DateAdded, 
    Cast(DateAdded AS Date) AS DateAddedV1, 
    Cast(DateAdded AS Time) AS DateTime, 
    SELECT CAST(DateAdded AS Date(mm:dd) AS OrderDate
FROM Products
```

I am a beginner with SQL and I am trying to return the `DateAdded` column as `OrderDate` with only the month and the day but I cannot seem to get the syntax right. I appreciate anyone's assistance.

Comment: It should be noted that, as a rule, you shouldn't be formatting data for display in the database. That is a task usually handled by the application. This question sounds like it is based on a homework assignment, employment test or drunken dare.

Comment: This really looks like the homework problem I'm currently working on (OregonTech CST324 DB class, working from Murach's SQL Server 2012 for devs book): I wrote all the some lines except for the 4th (even same column and table names!), which is what I was stuck on. I would use CONVERT, but the assignment said use CAST.

Answer (score 3):

Use `DatePart` Function to extract `day` and `month` from `Datetime` type,

```
Select Datepart(Month,DateAdded) AS [Month], -- Month(Dateadded)
       Datepart(Day,DateAdded) as [Day], -- Day(Dateadded)
       ..
From   Products
```

**Update:** Only by using `cast` function you cannot extract `Month` and `Day`. If you want to keep month and day in same column

```
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), Month(DateAdded)) + ':'
           + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), Day(DateAdded)) 
           .....
```

To get leading zero's use `right` function and to extract `Time` from DateAdded use `Convert` function with `108` value

```
SELECT right('0'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), Month(DateAdded)),2) + ':'
       + right('0'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), Day(DateAdded)) ,2) as [Mon:Day],
         convert(varchar(10),DateAdded,108) as [Time]
       .........
```

Comment: @ZackSpideyDavidson They probably want you to use `CAST(DateAdded as Date)` - I don't think there is a way to use the `CAST` function to remove the year. Also, using `CAST` as a formatting tool is stupid.

Answer (score 2):

I think I'm working on this assignment this semester. This is what I ended up with since it HAD to be done using the CAST function:

```
SELECT DateAdded,
    CAST(DateAdded AS date) AS DateOnly,
    CAST(DateAdded AS time) AS TimeOnly,
    CAST(DateAdded AS varchar(6)) MonthDay
FROM Products;
```

This works because varchar always has the Month the Day exactly in the first 6 characters. All the Months are 3 Characters (Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr) and then there is either a space then a 2-digit day, or 2 spaces and a 1-digit day. Either way it always adds up to 6 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are asking about the visible format of date/time information.

- In MS SQL Server from SQ 2012 and later you can use a [FORMAT()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/hh213505.aspx)
  function. If you use a version that supports this function I recommend you use it. Keep in mind that the second parameter is CASE SENSITIVE
- In all versions you may use the [CONVERT()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187928.aspx) function, which has
  this syntax:

> CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , **style** ] )

Note in paticular that **style** parameter (an integer) this is important if using CONVERT. A very useful reference for using either approach for display of date/time information is [**HERE**](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2012/format-function-vs-convert-function.aspx) and below is a tiny example:

[SQL Fiddle demo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/hh213505.aspx)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
      FORMAT(SYSDATETIME(), 'MMM dd yyyy')  
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), SYSDATETIME(), 100) -- note length set to (11)
```

**[Results](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187928.aspx)**:

```
|-------------|-------------|
| Oct 11 2015 | Oct 11 2015 |
```

Comment: FORMAT() is worst in terms of performance. You can read about it here: https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but
I found that MONTH('Date') and YEAR('Date') methods are works faster than anything by orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting, as in NoDisPlayName's answer, you could use the `RTRIM` functionality.

`SELECT RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(MONTH(DateAdded)), 2)`